# Write a spark dataframe with few struct columns and few int/string columns?

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For example, consider the below data frame-

[image]

I want to write this to Postgres and the end table should have all the columns, not a stringified one column. I can not explode multiple arrays at this level (business logic).

Comment: Can add some sample input data and expected output? The ask in the question was not clear..

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you want to process struct fields as their own tables:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

def get_struct_dfs(df):
  result_dfs = []
  for column in df.columns:
     if isinstance(df.schema[column].dataType, (ArrayType, )):
          exploded_df = df.select(explode(column))
          result_dfs.extend(process(exploded_df))
     elif isinstance(df.schema[column].dataType, (StructType, )):
          exploded_df = df.select(f"{column}.*")
          result_dfs.append(exploded_df)
  return result_dfs
```

Comment: This partially answers my question as I did not want to explode array columns. Also to convert a struct column into a string, I think we could simply use to_josn function.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a pretty simple solution to use to_json to convert [[StructType]] to a JSON string that is supported in Postgres.

`for c in df.columns:
    if c is in ["arrCol1", "arrCol2", "arrCol3"]:
        df = df.withColumn(c, to_json(c))`

This would convert the array of structs to string type.